# html parser error message: Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, navigateurl

I am getting the error **Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.** on the code line below:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="imgFileType" ImageUrl="images/Icon_Pdf.gif" NavigateUrl='<%#"javascript:ViewFile('erg_", Eval("DocumentName") %>' runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

I need the url link to be parsed as:

```
javascript:ViewFile('erg_Invoice_3200_QRG_Restaurant.pdf');
```

What am I missing in the syntax?

Comment: Can you please post your entire server tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that. The single quote double quote mess will make the compiler complain.
Please write a helper.

Markup

```
NavigateUrl='<%# SetNavigateUrl(Eval("DocumentName")) %>'>
```

Code-Behind

```
protected string SetNavigateUrl(object objName)
{
    return String.Format("javascript:ViewFile('erg_{0}');", objName.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I am using the hyperlink control, which does not have an OnClientClick event.

Comment: Thank you @Naveen. Time for me to go to bed :-) Cheers !!